# show $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{1}{ |x| } + \frac{1}{ |y|} = \infty $

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{1}{ |x| } + \frac{1}{ |y|} = \infty $$

I tried to make cases but not able to prove

Comment: May be easier to tackle one term at a time, since you know that if lim A and lim B both exist, then so does lim (A+B) and this equals their sum.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

Let $M > 0$.  What happens to $\dfrac{1}{|x|} + \dfrac{1}{|y|}$ as soon as $|x| < 1/M$?  as soon as $|y| < 1/M$?  This gives a square, centered on the origin in which the value of your function is large.  Are there any sequences of $(x,y)$ pairs that go to $(0,0)$ but avoid this square?

This also gives you many opportunities to find a region in that square for which you can make your inequalities work ... but I think that square is the easiest one to go for.

Comment: to go toorigin one has to pass through square. can you elaborate bit more?

Comment: A disk of radius $1/M$ sits inside the square.

Comment: I don't seem to understand the point